# phpbrew install specific php version build fail(make: *** [sapi/cli/php] ERROR 1)

Tags: php, linux

i have some problems when i use phpbrew install php. i use:

```
phpbrew install 5.3.10 +default +apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
```

show me a error:

```
Build failing with error:
/home/admin/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.10/ext/dom/node.c: In function 'dom_canonicalization':
/home/admin/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.10/ext/dom/node.c:1898:21: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home/admin/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.10/esolutionxt/dom/node.c:1900:5: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
make: *** [ext/dom/node.lo] Error 1
```

so i am google and find a solution------>build with a patch:

```
 phpbrew install --patch /path/to/patch 5.3.10 +default +apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
```

patch URL:https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2012-August/txtbgxGXAvz4N.txt

but i got a different error:

```
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x5d1): undefined reference to `php_pcre_fullinfo'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x5f1): undefined reference to `php_pcre_fullinfo'
ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `php_pcre_replace_impl.constprop.13':
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x113c): undefined reference to `php_pcre_fullinfo'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x1316): undefined reference to `php_pcre_exec'
ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache':
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x175b): undefined reference to `php_pcre_compile'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x18a2): undefined reference to `php_pcre_info'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x1949): undefined reference to `php_pcre_maketables'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x196a): undefined reference to `php_pcre_study'
ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `php_pcre_match_impl':
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x2541): undefined reference to `php_pcre_fullinfo'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x2621): undefined reference to `php_pcre_exec'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x2670): undefined reference to `php_pcre_get_substring_list'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x2ba2): undefined reference to `php_pcre_free'
ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `php_pcre_replace_impl':
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x31e9): undefined reference to `php_pcre_fullinfo'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x32ea): undefined reference to `php_pcre_exec'
ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `php_pcre_split_impl':
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x4624): undefined reference to `php_pcre_fullinfo'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x4701): undefined reference to `php_pcre_exec'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x4b4f): undefined reference to `php_pcre_exec'
ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `php_pcre_grep_impl':
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x4db9): undefined reference to `php_pcre_fullinfo'
php_pcre.c:(.text+0x4f9a): undefined reference to `php_pcre_exec'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] ERROR 1
```

I did not find any solution，any idea？ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem and fixed it installing all requirements for ubuntu.

I used this [manual on github](https://github.com/c9s/phpbrew/wiki/Requirement#ubuntu-1304-requirement)